# How to log Websphere connection pool information like active connections in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling, websphere-liberty

We are using Websphere liberty 20.0.0.12 and spring boot (parent) version 2.0.5.

I can find the connection pool information in the JConsole.

How can I print Websphere connection pool information in application logs?

(Read comments of approved answer if using liberty server instead of traditional websphere application server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM support doc at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-enable-connection-pool-trace-websphere-application-server describes how to enable printing of various connection pool stats in the trace log for traditional WAS, for Liberty, you'll use the same trace specification `WAS.j2c=all:RRA=all`(you don't need Transaction) and put a `logging` element in your server config file (typically server.xml).  See Liberty doc at https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/log-trace-configuration.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can't see integrated solution console when I type "../ibm/console". I manually didn't  install any websphere software in my pc, I downloaded it from eclipse. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: The integrated solutions console is part of the traditional version of WebSphere app server, and not available for Liberty.  Please provide a link to the eclipse download you're using.  You should be able to go to the "Servers" view and see a server created for Liberty.  Under that instance you should be able to see the configuration files for Liberty, one of which will be server.xml, that is where you will add it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I found workaround while finding solution to this problem. That is to add monitor-1.0 feature to expose connection pool information and then adding jolokia to access connection pool information remotely and to log into application log by calling jolokia endpoint. I also found this link for logging information to trace.log file as you suggested:https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/set-trace-and-get-full-dump-websphere-liberty